# What is the additive analogue of the word "factor"?

Tags: terminology

When we have a bunch of numbers multiplied together like
$$b=a_1\,a_2\,a_3\,a_4,$$
we say that each $a_i$ is a **factor** of $b$.

What is the additive analogue of this terminology? That is, if
$$b=a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4,$$
how is $a_i$ called?

Comment: Those are summands

Comment: They are also called terms.

Comment: "Summands", as in a previous comment, or "terms".

Comment: "Summand" is better; "term" can also be an element of a sequence.

Comment: See also augend, addend.

Comment: "addend" (also).

Comment: You can say that $a_i$ belongs to one of the [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of $b$, and to one of the [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) of $b$.

Answer (score 1):

The additive analogue for multiplicative `factors` is `summand`.

An `augend` + `addend` = `sum` / `total`

Also `summand` + `summand` = `sum`

The equivalent of `factorization` could be called as `summandization`

For more information, check this out (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/summand)